# Django doesn't recive pre save signal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request, signals

I'm writing DRF appliaction and I have problem which I can't understand. I'm trying to send request when my model changes.

Here is my model:

```
class Sensors(models.Model):

    CATEGORIES = [
        ('temperature', 'temperature'),
        ('humidity', 'humidity'),
    ]
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CATEGORIES)
    battery_level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(default=300)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sensor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sensors"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

And here is my signal.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from sensors.models import Sensors 
import requests


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Sensors)
def do_something_if_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        sensor = Sensors.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except Sensors.DoesNotExist:
        pass # Object is new, so field hasn't technically changed, but you may want to do something else here.
    else:
        if not sensor.frequency == instance.frequency: # Field has changed
            # do something
            data_for_sensor = {
                'id': sensor.id,
                'frequency': instance.frequency
            }
            response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.21:8000/receive', data=data_for_sensor)
            response.raise_for_status()
```

Generally post is not sending and I cannot find why

also here is my apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class SensorsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'sensors'
    def ready(self):
        from .models import Sensors
        Sensors = self.get_model('Sensors')

        pre_save.connect(receiver, sender='sensors.Sensors')
```

and my init.py:

```
default_app_config = 'sensors.apps.SensorsConfig'
```

Comment: It sounds like your receiver isn't being registered. Did you import this function in the apps' AppConfig class's ready function as mentioned in the notes? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Comment: You can also register receivers in other parts of your project if you feel it's cleaner.

Comment: @schillingt did you mean something like this?

`from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class SensorsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'sensors'
    def ready(self):
        Sensors = self.get_model('Sensors')

        pre_save.connect(receiver, sender='sensors.Sensors')
`
If yes, this solution still doesn't work

Comment: Can we redirect from signal ? Why Request.post() is used in ? I want to know.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanFareed Generally if someone changes frequency value in Sensor model I want to send POST request to physical sensor with new value of frequency

Answer (score 0):

This is my standard practice for wiring up the receivers in a `receivers.py` file

```
#apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class SensorsConfig(AppConfig):    
    name = 'sensors'
    def ready(self):
         from . import receivers
```